# structs in C and .h files

Tags: c, struct

I am confused on structs in c.  I am trying to create a .h file that has all the structs that I will be using.  I created structs.h

```
#include <ucontext.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct TCB_t;

typedef struct
{
    struct TCB_t * next;
    struct TCB_t * previous;
    ucontext_t context;
    int val;
}TCB_t;
```

my TCB.h file

```
#include "structs.h"



int count =0;
struct TCB_t *RunQ = NULL;
struct TCB_t *ptr = NULL;

void init_TCB (struct TCB_t *tcb, void *function, void *stackP, int stack_size, int *arg)
{
    memset(tcb, '\0', sizeof(struct TCB_t));
    getcontext(&tcb->context);
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_sp = stackP;
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_size = (size_t)stack_size;
    makecontext(&tcb->context, function, 1, arg);

}
```

When I run I get the following errors.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Field 'ss_size' could not be resolved   TCB.h   /projThree/src  line 14 Semantic Error


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Field 'ss_sp' could not be resolved TCB.h   /projThree/src  line 13 Semantic Error


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Field 'uc_stack' could not be resolved  TCB.h   /projThree/src  line 13 Semantic Error


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Field 'uc_stack' could not be resolved  TCB.h   /projThree/src  line 14 Semantic Error


  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Symbol 'NULL' could not be resolved TCB.h   /projThree/src  line 6  Semantic Error


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Symbol 'NULL' could not be resolved TCB.h   /projThree/src  line 7  Semantic Error
```

If I move the struct fron structs.h to TCB.h the errors go away.  Why is this and shouldn't TCB.h have access to the structs in structs.h because I included "structs.h" on the top of the page?

Comment: Function definition in a .h file?

Comment: Depends where `structs.h` is located. Perhaps try `#include <structs.h>`. Also, function definitions should go into `.c` files instead.

Comment: I am a little confused.  I am using c for a class I am taking.  He has us using the function definitions in .h files

Comment: So what should I do instead?  I know C++ but so far c is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: @bwinata, I tried <structs.h> and am still getting the same error

Comment: You need to check the path of your `structs.h` file and make sure it's correctly linked in your Makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you've declared that there is a `struct TCB_t` somewhere, and you've defined a `typedef` with the name `TCB_t` for a tagless (anonymous) `struct` type, but you've not defined the type `struct TCB_t`.

```
struct TCB_t;    // There is, somewhere, a type struct TCB_t

typedef struct   // This is an anonymous struct, not a struct TCB_t
{
    struct TCB_t * next;
    struct TCB_t * previous;
    ucontext_t context;
    int val;
} TCB_t;         // This is a typedef for the anonymous struct
```

You need to write either this:

```
typedef struct TCB_t TCB_t;

struct TCB_t
{
    TCB_t      *next;       // Optionally struct TCB_t
    TCB_t      *previous;   // Optionally struct TCB_t
    ucontext_t  context;
    int         val;
};
```

or this:

```
typedef struct TCB_t
{
    struct TCB_t *next;
    struct TCB_t *previous;
    ucontext_t    context;
    int           val;
} TCB_t;
```

Both end up with `struct TCB_t` and a plain type `TCB_t` which is an alias for `struct TCB_t`.

Beware, the `_t` suffix is officially reserved for use by the implementation (the compiler and supporting libraries).  You might run into problems using it yourself (but probably won't until it is uncomfortably late to change the name).

And the reason for your compilation errors is that the compiler hasn't been told what a `struct TCB_t` contains, so you can't access the `context` member of it, and hence not the fields within the `context` member.